How to add delay to Apache Beam WriteToJdbc for MySQL Database
I am trying to stream data from a Google Cloud Pub/Sub to a MySQL Cloud Database for a uni project. The data contains a series of values for various attributes of which some need to go into one table and some into another. For the first table (flights), the stream data duplicates the values so only one instance of it is required and for the other table (tickets) it contains all the unqiue values associated with the one instance.
import argparse
import json
import os
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromPubSub
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import WriteToJdbc
from apache_beam.transforms.window import FixedWindows

with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = config['google_credentials']

SCHEMA = '''
Flight_ID:STRING, Flight_Status:STRING, Aircraft_ID:STRING,
Destination_Airport:STRING, Departure_Airport:STRING,
Departure_Time:TIMESTAMP, Arrival_Time:TIMESTAMP,
Passport_No:STRING, Model_ID:STRING, Seat_No:INTEGER, Citizenship:STRING
'''

def to_flight_row(element):
    return beam.Row(
        Flight_ID=str(element['Flight_ID']),
        Flight_Status=str(element['Flight_Status']),
        Aircraft_ID=str(element['Aircraft_ID']),
        Destination_Airport=str(element['Destination_airport']),
        Departure_Airport=str(element['Departure_airport']),
        Departure_Time=str(element['Departure_Time']),
        Arrival_Time=str(element['Arrival_Time']),
        Model_ID=str(element['Model_ID'])
    )

def to_ticket_row(element):
    return beam.Row(
        Passport_No=str(element['Passport_No']),
        Citizenship=str(element['Citizenship']),
        Seat_No=int(element['Seat_No']),
        Flight_ID=str(element['Flight_ID']),
    )

def run_pipeline(input_subscription, flight_table, ticket_table):
    import apache_beam as beam
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, streaming=True, streaming_engine_option='DATA_FLOW_SERVICE')
    pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project = known_args.project_id

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        messages = (
                p
                | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
                | "Log Data" >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"Writing Flight Data: {x}") or x)
                | "Decode JSON messages" >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
        )

    windowed_messages = messages | "Apply Windowing" >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(30))

    flight_data = (
            windowed_messages
            | "Extract Flight Data" >> beam.Map(to_flight_row)
            | "Deduplicate Flight Data" >> beam.Distinct()
    )

    flight_data | "Log Flight Data" >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"Writing Flight Data: {x}") or x)

    flight_data | "Write Flight Data to Cloud SQL" >> WriteToJdbc(
        table_name=flight_table,
        driver_class_name='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
        jdbc_url=config['jdbc_url'],
        username=config['db_username'],
        password=config['db_password'],
    )

    ticket_data = (windowed_messages | "Extract Ticket Data" >> beam.Map(to_ticket_row))

    ticket_data | "Log Ticket Data" >> beam.Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"Writing Ticket Data: {x}") or x)

    ticket_data | "Write Ticket Data to Cloud SQL" >> WriteToJdbc(
        table_name=ticket_table,
        driver_class_name='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
        jdbc_url=config['jdbc_url'],
        username=config['db_username'],
        password=config['db_password']
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import apache_beam as beam

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--project_id", help="Your GCP project ID", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--input_subscription", help="Input PubSub subscription", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--flight_table", help="MySQL table for flight details", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--ticket_table", help="MySQL table for ticket details", required=True)
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    run_pipeline(known_args.input_subscription, known_args.flight_table, known_args.ticket_table)

The problem I have is I get a foreign key constraint error as the flight data doesn't seem to be loading in before the ticket data:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (airlines.Ticket, CONSTRAINT Ticket_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (Flight_ID) REFERENCES Flight (Flight_ID))
I tried adding a delay using windowing after the ticket data is extracted but that didn't make a difference.
ticket_data = (windowed_messages | "Extract Ticket Data" >> beam.Map(to_ticket_row))
    ticket_data_delayed = ticket_data | "Apply Ticket Windowing" >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(70))

